# Java: How do I prevent duplicates from being added to ArrayList using conditional statement?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist, boolean

I'm nearly finished with a program that gathers the user's inputs (keywords) and displays them. I have it functioning in that regard but I also need to prevent duplicate keywords from being added to the List using a conditional if statement. I know I'm on the right track, but having trouble wrapping my mind around the syntax and use of a boolean to compare the entered keyword with the existing ArrayList.

I know there are methods such as Hash/Set but I'd like to be able to do it with the conditional statement before I move onto other techniques. Every answer I've found in the search seems to explain the use of Hash.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Iv'e edited my code to what I currently have based on @Jacob 's answer and this is what I was looking for, so thanks for the response. But it's still not removing duplicates, it's like it's not checking the array and skipping right to `alreadyExists == false` conditional statement. Or am I not comparing the values correctly?

```
import java.util.*;

public class KeywordData {
    private ArrayList<Keyword> keywords = new ArrayList<Keyword>();

    public void create() {
        InputHelper inputHelper = new InputHelper();
        String prompt = "";
        boolean isTrue = true;

        while (isTrue) {
            prompt = inputHelper.getUserInput("Enter a string, otherwise type 'n' to exit:");
            if (!prompt.equals("n")) {
                Keyword keyword = new Keyword();
                keyword.setUserKeyword(prompt);

                boolean alreadyExists = false;
                for (Keyword keyword1 : keywords) {
                    if (keyword1.equals(keyword)) {
                        alreadyExists = true;
                    }
                }

                if (alreadyExists == false) {
                    keywords.add(keyword);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("You already added that word");
                }

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayKeywords() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("********** Your unique user keywords **********");
        for (Keyword keyword : keywords) {
            keyword.display();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not use the `contains` method?

Comment: `if (!keywords.contains(keyword)) keywords.add(keyword);`

Comment: thanks @shmosel for response. That compiles and runs but it displays nothing after I run the program. just the header with: 
"********** Your unique user keywords **********"

Comment: Probably a bug in your `display()` method. Also you need to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` if you want `contains()` to work.

Comment: You have to implement `equals(). You only need `hashCode()` for hash collections. @shmosel

Comment: @user207421 That would be a violation of the contract: *If two objects are equal according to the `equals(Object)` method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.*

Comment: @jpsweeney94 You should post your `Keyword` and `InputHelper` classes on here as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, I showed my whole program because I changed some of your custom classes to just strings, and didn't really know what those custom classes did.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.Console;

public class KeywordData {
    private ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void create() {
        String prompt = "";
        boolean isTrue = true;

        while (isTrue) {
            System.out.println("Enter a string, otherwise type 'n' to exit:");
            prompt = reader.next();
            if (!prompt.equals("n")) {

                boolean alreadyExists = false;
                for (String keyword1 : keywords) {
                    if (keyword1.equals(prompt)) {
                        alreadyExists = true;
                    }
                }
                if (alreadyExists == false) {
                    keywords.add(prompt);
                }else {
                    System.out.println("You already added that word");
                }

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayKeywords() {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("********** Your unique user keywords **********");
        for (String keyword : keywords) {
            System.out.println(keyword);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeywordData kd = new KeywordData();
        kd.create();
        kd.displayKeywords();
    }

}
```

But the easier way to check is like this

```
if (!prompt.equals("n")) {
    if (keywords.contains(prompt)) {
        System.out.println("You already added that word");
    }else {
        keywords.add(prompt);
    }               
} else {
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks, definitely the idea I was looking for! I've updated my post with your code (but still conforming to my classes) and it is adding items to array and displaying them, but not preventing duplicates. I suspect something is wrong with first array list loop...

Comment: @jpsweeney94 I would keep your code in the question the same. If you need to make an update, post it below your original question. When I run the program I made, it stops me and tells me if I'm entering a duplicate. You're saying you're still getting duplicates? Is perhaps one of your other functions appending to the array? LIke `keyword.setUserKeyword(prompt);` or something

Comment: Ok will remember that from now on, thanks @Jacob... And ya, I'm still getting duplicates and even though I have the boolean set up, it doesn't ever tell me I already entered that word. And I'm not sure, but the `Keyword` Class contains the `userKeyword` String variable and `keyword.setUserKeyword(prompt);` is the setter for the var. So that's what sets the object for the ArrayList. Id like to figure out how to do it using and Array of Obj references in separate classes instead of just doing a String array in the same class... but I'm getting to the point where I may just do that...

Comment: @jpsweeney94 In your modified version `keyword` is of type `Keyword` and `keyword1` is of type `string`, so no they won't be equal, can't you put you `Keyword` class up. You might wanna try something like `keyword.name` or `keyword.toString()`